# Display 1 when no data is exist in database

Tags: python, django, object, orm, not-exists

I am trying to generate incremental id whenever I am adding new data in my model. here I am getting the the next number whenever I am adding new data. but If there is no any data in my table its giving me error. **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tax_id'**

Here is my code

views.py

```
def tax_settings(request):
latest_id = (Tax_Settings.objects.last()).tax_id+1
if request.method == 'POST':
    tax_id = latest_id
    name = request.POST['tax_name']
    tax_percentage = request.POST['tax_percentage']
    tax_details=Tax_Settings.objects.create(tax_id=tax_id, name=name, tax_percentage=tax_percentage)
    tax_details.save()
    next_id = (Tax_Settings.objects.last()).tax_id+1
    return render(request,"settings/tax-settings.html",{"latest_id":next_id})
else:
    return render(request,"settings/tax-settings.html",{"latest_id":latest_id})
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{latest_id}}" name="tax_id"  disabled>
```

which condition I can give to my latest_id if data(tax_id) not exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do too much in too few lines of code. Wherever you use queryset `.last()` or `.first()` you must explicitly handle the case where it returns `None`!

You need code of the form:

```
o = Tax_Settings.objects.last()
if o is not None:
    tax_id = o.tax_id + 1
else:
    tax_id = 1 # if that's a sensible default value
```

or even

```
o = Tax_Settings.objects.last()
assert o is not None, "This can't happen!" # except obviously, it does in this question.
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you first create a single record than don't need to handle this or

```
tax_id = 0
latest_rec = (Tax_Settings.objects.last())
if latest_rec is not None:
    latest_id = latest_rec.tax_id+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add:

```py
if latest_id is None:
    latest_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you have issues with your first line in the provided function:
`latest_id = Tax_Settings.objects.last().tax_id+1`

when you have no data, i.e. `Tax_Settings.objects.last()` is `None`.

You should define default ID, for instance `0` which would be assigned in case of missing objects:

```
def tax_settings(request):
    if Tax_Settings.objects.last() is not None:
        # some data already stored
        latest_id = Tax_Settings.objects.last().tax_id
    else:
        # no data present yet
        latest_id = 0
    . . .
```

btw. I am not sure why are you incrementing the latest value in the beginning, but you need to take into account that if your default latest ID is `0` then the ID of the first data unit stored will be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code also works:

```py
tax_data=Tax_Settings.objects.all()
    if not tax_data:
        print("no data found")
        latest_id=1
    else:
        latest_id = (Tax_Settings.objects.last()).tax_id+1
```